# How to decode column value from rare label by matching column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have two dataframes like as shown below

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import default_rng
rng = default_rng(100)
cdf = pd.DataFrame({'Id':[1,2,3,4,5],
                   'grade': rng.choice(list('ACD'),size=(5)),
                   'dash': rng.choice(list('PQRS'),size=(5)),
                   'dumeel': rng.choice(list('QWER'),size=(5)),
                   'dumma': rng.choice((1234),size=(5)),
                   'target': rng.choice([0,1],size=(5))
})

tdf = pd.DataFrame({'Id': [1,1,1,1,3,3,3],
                   'feature': ['grade=Rare','dash=Q','dumma=rare','dumeel=R','dash=Rare','dumma=rare','grade=D'],
                   'value': [0.2,0.45,-0.32,0.56,1.3,1.5,3.7]})
```

My objective is to

a) Replace the `Rare` or `rare` values in `feature` column of `tdf` dataframe by original value from `cdf` dataframe.

b) To identify original value, we can make use of the string before `= Rare` or `=rare` or `= rare` etc. That string represents the column name in `cdf` dataframe (from where original value to replace `rare` can be found)

I was trying something like the below but not sure how to go from here

```
replace_df = cdf.merge(tdf,how='inner',on='Id')
replace_df ["replaced_feature"] = np.where(((replace_df["feature"].str.contains('rare',regex=True)]) & (replace_df["feature"].str.split('='))])
```

I have to apply this on a big data where I have million rows and more than 1000 replacements to be made like this.

I expect my output to be like as shown below

[image]

Comment: you have not explained how your replaced `dumma=rare` with `dumma=1123` and `dumma=849` in row #2 and 5 respectively. Perhaps you can expand b) by explaining how you selected values for replacement for each of the `rare`/`Rare` rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible approach using `MultiIndex.map` to substitute values from `cdf` into `tdf`:

```py
s = tdf['feature'].str.split('=')
m = s.str[1].isin(['rare', 'Rare'])
v = tdf[m].set_index(['Id', s[m].str[0]]).index.map(cdf.set_index('Id').stack())

tdf.loc[m, 'feature'] = s[m].str[0] + '=' + v.astype(str)
```

---

```
print(tdf)

   Id     feature  value
0   1     grade=D   0.20
1   1      dash=Q   0.45
2   1  dumma=1123  -0.32
3   1    dumeel=R   0.56
4   3      dash=P   1.30
5   3   dumma=849   1.50
6   3     grade=D   3.70
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# list comprehension to find where rare is in the feature col
tdf['feature'] = [x if y.lower()=='rare' else x+'='+y for x,y in tdf['feature'].str.split('=')]
# create a mask where feature is in columns of cdf
mask = tdf['feature'].isin(cdf.columns)
# use loc to filter your frame and use merge to join cdf on the id and feature column - after you use stack
tdf.loc[mask, 'feature'] = tdf.loc[mask, 'feature']+'='+tdf.loc[mask].merge(cdf.set_index('Id').stack().to_frame(),
                                                                            right_index=True, left_on=['Id', 'feature'])[0].astype(str)

   Id     feature  value
0   1     grade=D   0.20
1   1      dash=Q   0.45
2   1  dumma=1123  -0.32
3   1    dumeel=R   0.56
4   3      dash=P   1.30
5   3   dumma=849   1.50
6   3     grade=D   3.70
```

Answer (score 1):

My feeling is there's no need to look for `Rare` values.
Extract the column name from `tdf` to lookup in `cdf`. After, flatten your `cdf` dataframe to extract the right values:

```
r = tdf.set_index('Id')['feature'].str.split('=').str[0].str.lower()

tdf['feature'] = r.values + '=' + cdf.set_index('Id').unstack() \
                                     .loc[zip(r.values, r.index)] \
                                     .astype(str).values
```

Output:

```
>>> tdf
   Id     feature  value
0   1     grade=D   0.20
1   1      dash=Q   0.45
2   1  dumma=1123  -0.32
3   1    dumeel=R   0.56
4   3      dash=P   1.30
5   3   dumma=849   1.50
6   3     grade=A   3.70

>>> r
Id           # <- the index is the row of cdf
1     grade  # <- the values are the column of cdf
1      dash
1     dumma
1    dumeel
3      dash
3     dumma
3     grade
Name: feature, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks. Same for you well documented question! Let me know if you need more explanation.

Comment: I will fix my answer because my feeling isn't right :)

Comment: while I realize now that there is no need to identify `rare` values (for this data), how would you know which records to replace? of course, column names are matching..So, you assume that all values other than rare/Rare/RARE will be exact match with Original value in `cdf` dataframe?

Comment: Yes that's right but the last row transform `grade=D` to `grade=A`...

Comment: *all values other than rare/Rare/RARE will be exact match with Original value in cdf dataframe?* I believed it was true but what about the last row?

Comment: exactly. I think use of rare keyword will make sure that we touch only those records. But yes, not all values for other records will be exact matching with cdf columns..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241788/discussion-between-the-great-and-corralien).